# Performance of tail function for Scala Arrays

Tags: arrays, scala, performance

[Scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) says that the performance of **tail** for an Array sequence is *Linear* while **head** performance is *Constant*. Since the whole block that contains array elements is brought to cache, I don't expect to see any difference between head and tail for an array. I appreciate if someone explains why tail performance for arrays in Scala is linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tail function creates a new array containing all of the elements except the first.  To do this we need to create a copy of the array (minus the first element), which is a linear time operation. As the array gets larger there is more to copy.

Use `List` instead if you require efficient head and tail operations.

You may be confusing tail with last

- `head` gets the first element: O(1) for List and Array
- `last` gets the last element: O(n) for List, O(1) for Array
- `tail` gets everything except the first: O(1) for List, O(n) for Array
- `init` gets everything except the last: O(n) for List and Array

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty big difference between *lists* and *arrays*. `head` and `tail` are the canonical interface to lists, which in Scala, are singly linked lists. `head` refers to the first thing in the list and `tail` refers to all of the elements after the first. Since linked lists implement the tail as a pointer, this operation is a constant time operation.

However, things are a little different for arrays. Arrays are used for fast random access and refers to a contiguous block of memory. Scala still exposes the list-like interface of `head` and `tail`, but it has to do things a little differently to simulate that. In order to simulate `tail`, it has to make a new array containing all elements except the first. It has to copy all of its values into a new array, which is a linear time operation.